# Selection Formula where value is in a DataTable

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable, crystal-reports, selection

My system has a database table for orders (`Sales Lines`) and a table that stores customer addresses (`Customer_Addresses`). Each customer may have up to 10 addresses.

I need to create Crystal Reports to get all orders between a specified date range, where the customer is in a selected country. Such as between `01/01/2016` - `31/12/2016` in the UK.

I have considered selecting all address codes where `Country = selected_country` from `Customer_Addresses`, then storing the results in a `DataTable`. Then I'd use a selection formula of `{Sales Lines.Order_Date} >= myDate AND {Sales Lines.Order_Date} <= myOtherDate AND {Sales Lines.Address} = (One of the codes within the DataTable)`

What code would I need after `{Sales Lines.Address} =` to search for records where the address code in `Sales Lines.Address` is also stored in the `DataTable` I created when selecting from `Customer_Addresses`?

Comment: Have you provided user any parameter to enter codes?

Comment: @Siva Address codes? No, They're entered in the customer screen, this is on a separate form. The parameter chosen on this form would be the country that they're reporting on, where they choose it in a combobox

Comment: Can you describe the structures of your tables in details? I could write a single query that would solve the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal Reports has a simple functionality for this kind of tasks:

Just join from `Sales Lines` to `Customer_Adresses`. 
Now you can set your date filter and your country filter directly. 
You will have duplicates in your data if more than one customer address for the same order matches with the country code. But this is no problem. Crystal Reports has a option to enforce distinct data. Just activate this option in the database menu (it will use a `DISTINCT` in SQL)...